# Soap serialization multiple type of variables

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I'm trying to figure out a way to serialize multiple type of variables (list, sortedlist and an object) into a single file. These are the different things I'd like to serialize.

```
static public List<Departement> ListeDepartement;
static public SortedList<string, List<Employes>> ListeDepartementEmp = new SortedList<string, List<Employes>>();
static public Entreprise1 uneEntreprise;
```

This is what the class looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Entreprise
{
[Serializable()]
public class Entreprise1
{
    private string stNom;
    private string stAdressePrinc;
    private string stActivite;

    static public List<Departement> ListeDepartement;
    static public SortedList<string, List<Employes>> ListeDepartementEmp = new SortedList<string, List<Employes>>();
    static public Entreprise1 uneEntreprise;


    public string Nom
    {
        get { return stNom; }
        set { stNom = value; }
    }

    public string AdressePrinc
    {
        get { return stAdressePrinc; }
        set { stAdressePrinc = value; }
    }

    public string Activite
    {
        get { return stActivite; }
        set { stActivite = value; }
    }

    public Entreprise1() { }

    public Entreprise1(string pNom, string pAdressePrinc, string pActivite) 
    {
        Nom = pNom;
        AdressePrinc = pAdressePrinc;
        Activite = pActivite;
    }


    public string AfficherEntreprise(Entreprise1 pEntreprise)
    {
        string stChaine;
        stChaine = "Nom :" + pEntreprise.Nom + "\n" + "Adresse principale :" + pEntreprise.AdressePrinc + "\n" + "Activité :" + pEntreprise.Activite + "\n";
        return stChaine;
    }
}
}
```

I tried serializing the Entreprise1 class, but I'm having issues with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Only the instance properties of an object you are serializing will be serialized. Your static properties would be omitted. If you really want to serialize the static properties you would need to wrap them in another struct/class and keep an instance of this class as a static variable.

Comment: Alright, is there a way to copy a `SortedList<string, List<Employes>>` into another non-static SortedList. From what I know, a SortedList can't be copied into another one in a single line.

Comment: It depends what you mean by copy a SortedList?
a) copy a reference to a list
b) create another list with references to the same objects that the original list contains
c) create another list with references to copies of objects that the original list contains
Because based on your answer, the solution would be much different.

Comment: In another class, `Entreprise1 ent = new entreprise1();` followed by `SortedList<string, List<Employes>> ListDepartementSerialize;` and then `ListeDepartementEmp = ent.ListeDepartement;`